# How do you tell if an imported library ever gets use by the end user?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, web, analytics

I'm pretty new to software but I have a strong stats background and naturally I want everything to tell me how useful it really is.

At my work we have a pretty large web app that makes calls for big files.  I would really like to start paring down on what is called and used but I am not sure where to start because I am not sure what files are actually getting used.

We have millions of visitors that use our app every month.  We are using Angular 1 and Foundations along with a bunch of other things.  **If it is possible I would like to track if a foundations or angular library is requested, the size of the file, and if it was used.**

Has anyone done something similar to this before?  I know how to check and see if a function is used but I'm not sure the best way to get started on something like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Analyze any logs you can find**

You can start by analyizing the server logs, if your server is using apache the logs will be in /var/log/apache2

If your server is on tomcat in java it would be in catalina.out.

Reguardless once you get the log files, you will want to run a regular expression or an endswith on the logs to get logs ending in .js.

A quick python script should get this done

```
from collections import defaultdict
freq = defaultdict(lambda:0);

with open("mylogfile.txt", "r") as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
         if (line.endswith(('.js', '.css')):
            freq[line] += 1;
for key,val in freq.iteritems():
    print (key,val);
```